# Translate macro with parameters into template

Tags: c++

Is it possible to "modernize" macro-class definitions with some templates ? we have the code below, and I don't succeed doing it:

```
#define OPERATOR_CLASS(name, op, strOp) class name : public Node     \
    { private: Node *left, *right;                                   \
    public: name() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}                \
    double value()  { return left->value() op right->value(); }      \
    std::string print()  { return "(" + left->print() + strOp + right->print() + ")"; } \
};

//Classes to be expanded:
OPERATOR_CLASS(Add, +, "+")
OPERATOR_CLASS(....
```

I tried many combinations of std::functional and other std::plus(), nothing works. What I have missed ? Thank you.

Comment: Next to impossible to say what you have missed without seeing what you have tried. I recommend adding one or two of your more successful attempts along with a bit more context of what you want the result to to do.

Comment: I understand your point. I was just thinking that the question: traduce that macro into a template was self explanatory, without to write plenty of my shamefull & embarrassing errors...  :-) Jarod42 below explained perfectly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do:

```
template <typename Op, const char* name>
class OperatorClass : public Node
{
private:
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
public:
    OperatorClass() = default;
    OperatorClass(Node* left, Node* right) : left(left), right(right) {}
    double value() const { return Op{}(left->value(), right->value()); }
    std::string print()  { return "(" + left->print() + name + right->print() + ")"; }
};
```

With usage:

```
static const char plus_str[] = " + ";
using NodePlus = OperatorClass<std::plus<>, plus_str>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcfea8ae62ba6fea)

Comment: Thank you sincerely, and the Demo is absolutely nice. I was far from this, and to imagine that the { } is needed after the "op" term.
1. Could you briefly elaborate on it ?
2. Also, is there a way to write the " + " of plus_str, directly in the template parameter, like: OperatorClass<std::plus<>, " + "> node_plus{&n1, &n2};
3. What is the advantage of node_plus{&n1, &n2}; vs node_plus(&n1, &n2);

Comment: `Op` is a type, so to use `operator()`, you need an instance, `Op()` or `Op{}` for default constructor.

Comment: I think that in C++20, you might use `std::string_view` to have directly: `OperatorClass<std::plus<>, " + ">`. but before, you have to create static array.

Comment: Ok I see for the {} or (). Both work. As for the string_view, I did not succed with VisualStudio19 with experimental (they  do not have the 2020 yet, I beleive). Also, string_view does not mix well with other string or view, to build a resulting string. I turned around this by passing the " + " inside the constructor, and this works fine.